# How to view memory usage for mutations in ClickHouse?

Tags: clickhouse

I'm performing `alter table update` mutation and want to know how much memory is used by it.

I looked into `system.query_log` but there are all zeros in `read_rows/read_bytes/written_rows/written_bytes/memory_usage`. `system.mutations` also doesn't contain this information.

Is there a way to get it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

system.merges where is_mutation

Comment: Thanks, I didn't know about it, but looks like it stores only ongoing mutations (unlike query_log), nevertheless it is better than nothing.